# thymeleaf - th:switch boolean to i18n value

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Already I can get messages from the resource bundle in my application, but I need to show the internationalized value from a boolean attribute on a table.

I tried this:

```
<td th:switch="${boolean}">
    <span th:if="${boolean} = 'true'" th:text="#{messages.true}"/>
    <span th:if="${boolean} = 'false'" th:text="#{messages.false}"/>
</td>
```

But there was nothing displayed on the table.

What have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements) switch statement is the same to one in Java, so your statement should look like:

```
<td th:switch="${boolean}">
    <span th:case="true" th:text="#{messages.true}"/>
    <span th:case="false" th:text="#{messages.false}"/>
</td>
```

or you can achieve it even without switch statement as written in the [Messages](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#messages) paragraph of the documentation:

```
<td>
    <span th:text="#{messages.${boolean}}"/>
</td>
```